# Two Mongo repositories with different properties

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I've got two repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface SpringLRepository extends MongoRepository<L, String> {
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface SpringSRepository extends MongoRepository<S, String> {
}
```

In `properties` file i've got:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin

spring.data.mongodb.l.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.l.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.l.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.l.password=example
spring.data.mongodb.l.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.l.database=l

spring.data.mongodb.s.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.s.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.s.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.s.password=example
spring.data.mongodb.s.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.s.database=s
```

I want to have seperate properties for `SpringLRepository` and `SpringSRepository` or only change part of them like `spring.data.mongodb.database` parameter.

**I tried to follow this: [Configure Multiple MongoDB repositories with Spring Data Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681546/configure-multiple-mongodb-repositories-with-spring-data-mongo)**

First if i don't exclude `MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                //MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
        })
```

I've got:

```
Parameter 1 of method gridFsTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - mongoLTemplate: defined by method 'mongoLTemplate' in class path resource [...l/core/application/LMongoConfig.class]
    - mongoSTemplate: defined by method 'mongoSTemplate' in class path resource [...s/core/application/SMongoConfig.class]
```

**What can I do about it?**

Now I don't use `@Repository` anymore and I've added two classes.
First config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        basePackages = "...s.infrastructure.secondary.persistence",
        mongoTemplateRef = "mongoSTemplate"
)
public class SMongoConfig {
  @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.lead.host}")
  private String mongoHost;
  @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.lead.port}")
  private Integer mongoPort;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mongoSTemplate")
    MongoTemplate mongoSTemplate(@Qualifier("mongoSDbFactory") MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter converter) {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
        mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY);
        mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

@Bean
@Qualifier("mongoSimulationsDbFactory")
public MongoDbFactory mongoSimulationsDbFactory() {
    MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoOperations = MongoClientOptions.builder();
    mongoOperations.socketTimeout(1000 * 2);
    mongoOperations.connectTimeout(1000 * 2);
    MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("root", "admin", "example".toCharArray());
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(
            new MongoClient(
                    new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort),
                    Collections.singletonList(mongoCredential)
            ),
            "s");
}
}
```

Second config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        basePackages = "...l.infrastructure.secondary.persistence",
        mongoTemplateRef = "mongoLTemplate"
)
public class LMongoConfig{
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.l.host}")
    private String mongoHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.l.port}")
    private Integer mongoPort;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.l.database}")
    private String mongoDB;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.l.password}")
    private char[] mongoPassword;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mongoLTemplate")
    MongoTemplate mongoLTemplate(@Qualifier("mongoLDbFactory") MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter converter) {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
        mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY);
        mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mongoLDbFactory")
    public MongoDbFactory mongoLDbFactory() {
        MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoOperations = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        mongoOperations.socketTimeout(1000 * 2);
        mongoOperations.connectTimeout(1000 * 2);

    MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential("root", "admin", "example".toCharArray());
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(
                new MongoClient(
                        new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort),
                        Collections.singletonList(mongoCredential)
                ),
                "s");
    }
}
```

Now this code save `s` and `l` to seperate repositories but
I have a few concerns.
**`SimpleMongoDbFactory` and `MongoClient` are deprecated** and it's hard to find newer example of `Mongo` doing that.

Comment: The solution here worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938572/problems-with-qualifier/43938682#43938682

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the mongo repos from auto configuration. This is lifted from my app - which has more than just Mongo in there. Stick the pieces you need in your main application

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Then you'll have two configuration classes - one for each of the mongo databases that look a bit like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.mongo[n].repositories", mongoTemplateRef = "mongo[n]MongoTemplate")
public class Mongo[n]Configuration {

    @Autowired
    private MongoConfigurationProperties mongoProperties;

    @Bean(name = "Mongo[n]Template")
    public MongoTemplate mongo[n]Template() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(metadataFactory(this.mongoProperties.getMongo[n]()));
    }
 
    @Bean
    public SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory metadataFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
        // MongoClient mc = MongoClients.create(mongo.getUri());
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongo.getUri());
    }

}
```

It may not be exact - I edited on the fly to cut out organization names. Should be enough for you to get the idea though. Just make sure your package names match the repos at the top and you are gtg.

Also remember you'll need an @Primary on each bean in one of the config classes if you aren't auto wiring by name everywhere.

And lastly - as an aide-memoir - you need slightly different config if you ever move to document db. Google is your friend there - but the factory looks like this.

```
// Need this for documentdb
SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory factory = new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(MongoClients.create(mongo.getUri()), mongo.getDatabase());
```

Comment: can you show the full example, i need to exclude all the 
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration to work , and it will lose the repository

Comment: updated original to add context.